# display large txt files ( more than 50 MB )

Tags: android

How can i display large text files ( about 50 MB ) in Android ?

this is my last try but it's gives me OutOfMemoryError :

```
 BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
 StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
 String line;
 while((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
      total.append(line);
 }
 txtView.setText(total.toString());
```

How bookReaders or editors handle this kinds of problems ?( they also display text instantly )

Comment: Your code looks more or less right.  If that's giving you an OOM error, either you need to free up some memory elsewhere or you'll need to read the file in chunks as needed rather than reading it all in upfront.  That shouldn't be too bad, since if the text is that large you'll need to scroll it anyway.

Comment: how can i free up memory ? it's just a test app and i just read txt file and display that ?
later i wanna send it via wifi , you don't think chunks it get me in trouble ?

Comment: Use a vertical view pager, and read date in chunks https://github.com/LambergaR/VerticalViewPager/

Comment: thanks a lot :X , it's complicated but i try to figure it out :)